# Is there a shorter way to prevent "looping" through a not set array?

Tags: php, arrays, variables, null

I'm looking for an efficient/elegant way of avoiding `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` error if either the variable is not an array, or it is not set. Here's what I found out today (php `7.3.27`), which works :

```
foreach(isset($arr) ? (array)$arr : [] as $k=>$v) {
 // loop
}
```

is there a shorter/more elegant way of doing it ?

Comment: You could put the `isset` before the `foreach`. An empty array though won't run.

Comment: Ensure your variables are initialised to valid values…!?

Comment: Actually, I'd prefer `foreach` to work the same with _empty_ arrays as with _not set_ arrays... It'd be simpler :-)

Comment: Hint: [null-coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op).

Comment: Well… ultimately it's *simpler* to be extremely strict and sane about *what variables exist and what kinds of values they hold.* That saves you from having to test those two conditions at every turn…

Comment: @deceze, yes i get it. As per the comments/answer(s), and some tests, I see that I don't really need this kind of complicated one-liner test/action, as it appears, in the end, that _the data I'm dealing with is actually set at least to an empty array_... Thx for all your answers :-)

Answer (score 1):

Don't be concise. Be clear in what you mean:

```
if (empty($arr) OR !is_array($arr)) {
    return;
}

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    // …
}
```

Note that [type declaration](https://www.php.net/manual/language.types.declarations.php) in function can help you avoid the condition entirely.

Comment: You're right, I think what I'm looking for is 'brevity' rather than 'elegance'